# Replacement for lookbehind in std::regex

Tags: c++, regex

I need a regex to match tokens for a syntax highlighter, which should match full words when surrounded by non-alphanumeric characters or string boundaries. The regex I initially came up with is:

```
(?<=[^\w]|^)TOKEN(?=[^\w]|$)
```

Where `TOKEN` is the token I'm searching for. This works in regex testers, but c++'s regex doesn't support lookbehinds. Omitting the lookbehind causes the regex to match the character before the token as well, which causes issues. I'm aware boost::regex supports lookbehinds, but I'd like to keep to std::regex if possible.

My question is: can I change my regex to exclude the character before the token from the match?

Comment: Are you extracting matches (using regex (token) iterator) or just using `regex_replace`? Are you extracting multiple or a single match? Or do you just need a boolean result, true or false?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm extracting multiple matches with regex_iterator.

Comment: Ok, if the `TOKEN` can never start with a special char, you can use `R"(\bTOKEN(?!\w))"`. If it can never end with a special char, you can simply use `R"(\bTOKEN\b)"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is the pattern I ended up using, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is missing a closing `]` at the end, and `\w` also matches `\d`

You might use an alternation asserting either the start of the string, or a position where `\b` does not match and assert not a word char to the right.

```
(?:^|\B)TOKEN(?!\w)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pPMeOp/1)

After the update of the question, you can write `(?<=[^\w]|^)TOKEN(?=[^\w]|$)` as `(?<=\W|^)TOKEN(?=\W|$)` or in short without the lookbehind:

```
\bTOKEN(?!\w)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I misstyped my original pattern, it should be fixed now. As for your new answer, it works perfectly. Cheers!

Comment: @shon-r I think Wiktor is right, and you might also use the shortest version `\bTOKEN\b`

Comment: It depends on the `TOKEN`, if it is something totally arbitrary, no word boundaries will help.

Comment: Luckily every token the program needs to match is an unbroken word.